# how to get syntax assigned to a variable in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Is there a way in python to get the actual syntax assigned to a variable?  For example below when i assign ln = len(ec2.... and then when i print ln, i get the expected behavior...but what i am looking for is to get the actual syntax value assigned at any given point, so for example when i print ln(i know it wont work)  i should get value of "len(ec2.get_all_security_groups())".  i am not sure if it is even possible but wanted to ask...

```
>>> ln = len(ec2.get_all_security_groups())
>>> print ln
8
>>> dir(ln)
['__abs__', '__add__', '__and__', '__class__', '__cmp__', '__coerce__', '__delattr__', '__div__', '__divmod__', '__doc__', '__float__', '__floordiv__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__getnewargs__', '__hash__', '__hex__', '__index__', '__init__', '__int__', '__invert__', '__long__', '__lshift__', '__mod__', '__mul__', '__neg__', '__new__', '__nonzero__', '__oct__', '__or__', '__pos__', '__pow__', '__radd__', '__rand__', '__rdiv__', '__rdivmod__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__rfloordiv__', '__rlshift__', '__rmod__', '__rmul__', '__ror__', '__rpow__', '__rrshift__', '__rshift__', '__rsub__', '__rtruediv__', '__rxor__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__sub__', '__subclasshook__', '__truediv__', '__trunc__', '__xor__', 'bit_length', 'conjugate', 'denominator', 'imag', 'numerator', 'real']
>>>
```

Comment: I'm not aware of a way to do this, but it might help if you'll be more specific about what you're trying to achieve. For example, you could set the printed representation of objects by implementing their `__repr__` method.

Comment: This is a perfect example of an XY problem ( http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem ). Please describe what the actual problem you're trying to solve is, because this isn't it.

Comment: i am not trying to solve any specific problem, i am new to programming and this was just my curiosity.  I googled this for an hour or so before posting this online as i was not able to find an answer.  I thought it would be nice to print out what exactly the syntax of a variable is at any given point if your code is in 1000's of line.  Thats all..

Comment: No, you cannot do that. There are various debugging tools/IDEs for Python, I suggest you start researching those.

Comment: It sounds like you want a lambda, or even just a standard function.

Comment: Do  you actually want the source code?

Comment: What if `ln` had been assigned to in two different places: i.e. `ln = 1`, then later `ln += 41`, which "syntax" would you want?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham -- yes pretty much looking to get the code out

Comment: @maxscalf, are you looking to do this from an interpreter of from actual source files?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, from the interpreter

Answer (score 0):

Right now `ln` is just a number; you want it to be a function. You can define it as an inline function with `lambda`

```
ln = lambda: len(ec2.get_all_security_groups())
```

or as a regular function with `def`

```
def ln(): return len(ec2.get_all_security_groups())
```

The regular function method is usually preferred.

Answer (score -2):

Use triple quoting around your value

```
 ln = """len(ec2.get_all_security_groups())"""
```

result

```
ln
'len(ec2.get_all_security_groups())'
```

Comment: i think this kind of sort of does the trick but i do loose the value of whatever is assigned and this get converted into a comment.

Comment: You may consider rewording your question then.  The way you have the question worded this gives you exactly what you asked for.